# Modeling request response time

Tags: distributions, data-visualization

I have dataset collected by my application that tracks response time by different departments to a set of requests.  I'm trying to do some analysis of this data for management so they can track adherence to policy/SLA and target areas for improvement.

What would be an appropriate model for this type of data?  How would I best display this graphically to interested parties?

Here are some summary stats from the last month of requests:

```
Group    N   Min    Q1     Median  Q3      Max      Mean    StdDevP
Group3   41  2.033  7.433  15.016  22.016  260.733  23.399  40.370
Group4   30  1.816  9.670  20.624  25.479   59.283  19.479  12.826
Group9   22  3.316  5.016  16.25   29.804   95.216  21.872  21.425
Group11  68  0.733  6.320  13.558  26.962  152.95   22.031  28.652
Group13  77  0.816  9.566  19.583  36.75    80.55   25.105  19.210
Group14  51  5.15   11.00  22.983  37.208  169.8    29.547  28.166
Group15  65  2.133  8.383  21.483  32.016  118.583  22.938  19.157
Group18  77  2.133  5.4    14.9    22.6    335.25   44.111  85.835
Group20  59  2.3    10.58  20.766  30.216  686.683  34.228  87.375
Group21  42  4.583  8.879  19.866  26.791   81.666  20.473  14.168
Group23  28  2      18.64  32.099  74.204  189.3    51.680  47.629
Group26  74  0.283  7.749  22.483  33.291  340.116  29.243  42.027
Group31  52  1.283  6.679  13.066  26.054  393.183  27.886  56.151
```

Data is in hours from initial request to response.

Comment: What exactly is the question you're trying to answer?

Comment: @dsaxton: Well, given the skew of the data, it's obvious that this doesn't fit a standard normal distribution.  What kind of distribution makes sense from a theoretical model (given the type of data I'm collecting) or a data-driven one (give the descriptive statistics of the data above)?

Comment: @dsaxton: Once I know what sort of animal I'm dealing with, I hope that will lead me towards a standard / accepted way of displaying the data visually.